# Should I mantain Cloning Bay powered when traveling?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

When traveling through space you can encounter some events that kill some crew member, but having the Cloning Bay you can (sometimes) have a special option and "resurrect" them at the end.

To have the opportunity to do that is necessary to have the Cloning Bay powered with at least one power, or I can have it unpowered an still be able to have the "happy ending"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's safe to leave the clone bay unpowered. If it can save a crew member after an event, it will.

The cloning effect from events behaves like any blue event- it only checks the presence or absence of a system. Whether it is powered/damaged/on fire is irrelevant.

Comment: does it provide healing at jump if its unpowered?

Comment: @z-, yes, it does.

Comment: @z- Yes, it does. It is written in the in-game description explicitly.